# Using python to find missing blocks elements from a grid

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with two columns of data: X and Y which are coordinates. Both X and Y have the possible range 1 to 6.

However, there are some coordinates missing. The missing coordinates are (x1 to x2, y1 to y2 : 3 to 4, 2 to 5). I don't know what these missing coordinates are, I simply have the two columns (x,y) of existing coordinates:

```
X,Y
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
2 6
3 1
3 6
4 1
4 6
5 1
5 2
5 3
5 4
5 5
5 6
6 1
6 2
6 3
6 4
6 5
6 6
```

The increment along x and y should be regular and increasing by an integer. Given the above dataset, how would I find the missing ranges that I noted in the first paragraph? I specifically mean ranges because I don't want to dump a list of missing pairs. As the dataset I'm performing this on is approximately 5G I wanted the most pythonic way to do this. I am currently doing this with a loop and a consecutive count but I'm sure there is a better way.

The expected output would be a database that would look something like this:

```
X1 X2 Y1 Y2
3  4  2  5
```

In reality, there could be multiple 'blocks' of missing pairs and there could also be only 1 missing pair too.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You question is a bit unclear, especially on how you define the groups. Is the expected output the full output?

Comment: @mozway, tomorrow I am going to rewrite the question just using two columns instead of three. Two columns is what I will be dealing with most of the time and it will be much easier to explain

Comment: @Aldan looking forward to it ;)

Comment: @mozway it's been longer than I said but I have finally re-worded the question!

Comment: I don't understand the "*x1 to x2*". Do you simply want to find the missing combinations? Here (3/2, 3/3, 3/4, 3/5, 4/2, 4/3, 4/4…)

Comment: @mozway, yeah I want to find the missing combinations

Comment: can you provide the explicit expected output?

Comment: here is my [proposed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71112891/16343464) I hope this is what you want ;)

Comment: @mozway, i updated my question with the expected answer. The majority of your answer gives me what I need but I then need to group the missing pars into a range as per the expect output. Would you know how to do this quickly? If not, don't worry, you have helped me a lot anyway!!! Using the cross tab will really help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to find the missing combinations.

You could do the following.

Compute a crosstab, 0 will indicate the missing combinations:

```
ct = pd.crosstab(df['X'], df['Y'])

# Y  1  2  3  4  5  6
# X                  
# 1  1  1  1  1  1  1
# 2  1  1  1  1  1  1
# 3  1  0  0  0  0  1
# 4  1  0  0  0  0  1
# 5  1  1  1  1  1  1
# 6  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Convert to numpy array to get the indices of the missing values:

```
a = ct.eq(0).to_numpy()

import numpy as np
X,Y = np.where(a) 

# (array([2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Rescale the numpy indices to the indices of the crosstab and get the missing coordinates:

```
coords = list(zip(ct.index[X], ct.columns[Y]))
# [(3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: How to do it if the numbers are float instead of integers for e.g. lat long